# How to stop iOS11 from constantly asking to accept iCoud terms and conditions

Tags: ipad, icloud

Since I upgraded my iPad to iOS11 it is constantly popping up a little window asking me to accept the new iCloud terms and conditions. When I view the terms and conditions and DISAGREE (I have never used iCloud; signed up for iCloud; or want to use iCloud) it just goes back to popping up the little window constantly.
How can I get rid of this obnoxious window?

Any help greatly appreciated,
Ted

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Have you noticed any sort of pattern to when you get the prompt? I ask because iCloud is used for a lot of things, not just the more obvious ones you sign up for.